# Google auth - using data-use_fedcm_for_prompt but still browser shows error Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.postMessage call

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, fedcm

I have added a 'sign in with Google' button as per [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button)

My HTML code is:

```
 <div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="{{googleClientId}}" data-callback="handleCredentialResponse" data-use_fedcm_for_prompt="true"></div>
 <div class="g_id_signin" data-text="continue_with" ></div>
```

However when the user clicks the sign in button the error:  `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.postMessage call`. shows The google [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid) say that setting `data-use_fedcm_for_prompt` to true should prevent these errors.

Any way I can stop these errors?

Answer (score 0):

from the HTML code you attached, I assumed you are only using the [Sign In with Google button](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/personalized-button). FedCM is specific for [One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/features) for now. To resolve the error messages, you should still the [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid#cross_origin_opener_policy) to set up your COOP header.